# Group SQL Columns and count the results

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, sorting

How can I sort my database results into something like this using PHP. Basically, I am trying to group the results, and then count the results found in the database.

- Starcraft (1)
- League of Legends (4)
- Minecraft (2)
- Call of Duty: Black Ops (1)

I know there is a way, but I can't figure out the logic for this situation. If someone can give me an insight, that would be nice. Thank you!

Here is my SQL Table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a straightforward count and group by statement:

```
select
    game,
    count(*)
from
    yourTable
group by
    game
```

Based on this question, you should really take a read of this [question and answer I wrote for situations like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) as it explains in a lot of detail what is going on and how to get the results you want.